# Fast Way to compare subarray of bytes

Tags: java, arrays, compare, byte, mask

In the scope of a project that I'm currently working, I use binary data stored in arrays of 10 bytes, and I'm trying to find a fast way to compare them. I'm mostly interested in the 5 most significant bytes, so I want to perform a comparison between sub-arrays of bytes.
For instance, I have these two parameters:

```
byte [] indicator = new byte[5];
byte [] current = new byte[10];
```

I want to see of the 5 first bytes of the 'current' is equal to the 'indicator'. In order to do so, I'm using the Arrays functions, so I'm actually doing the following:

```
Arrays.equals(indicator, Arrays.copyOfRange(current, 0, 5))
```

This works fine of course, but not so fast as required. So I strongly believe that there must be a better way to perform such a byte comparison. Maybe by using `0xFF` masks???

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to copy it. Just write a manual function that iterates over the bytes and compares them. The copying process is what's slowing you down. `private static compareFirstNBytes(byte[] a, byte[] b, int n) {//}`

Comment: I'm curious - how fast is your attempt, and how fast does it need to be? Because I would have guessed your attempt was quite fast already (although a simple loop would be faster)

Comment: This won't make a huge difference...

Answer (score 5):

You may write your helper method, it would be faster, than allocation of a new copy:

```
public boolean equalsInRange (byte[] arr1, int from1, int to1, byte[] arr2, int from2, int to2) {
    if (to1 - from1 < 0 || to1 - from1 != to2 - from2)
        return false;
    int i1 = from1, i2 = from2;
    while (i1 <= to1) {
        if (arr1[i1] != arr2[i2])
            return false;
        ++i1;
        ++i2;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be faster just to iterate, as `copyOfRange` reallocates memory and creates a new array.

```
public boolean isEqual(byte[] a1, byte[] a2, int size) {
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        if (a1[i] != a2[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution for Java 9+:

```
Arrays.equals(indicator, 0, 5, current, 0, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(indicator).equals(ByteBuffer.wrap(current, 0, 5));
```

(should work in Java 6+, maybe even older)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).